# How to unit test google oauth passport in sails js with Mocha

Tags: oauth, tdd, google-oauth, sails.js, mocha.js

Right now I am trying to test my controllers and I need to access session, I found out that you can login using [superagent](http://jaketrent.com/post/authenticated-supertest-tests/) but my only option for loggin in to the web app is through google oauth, and right now I cannot find any appropriate samples for testing with Mocha. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you implemented your sessions.

In my Sails app, after authentication, I set `req.session.authenticated = true`, along with cookies, etc. One thing you can do if you're doing something similar is in your `/login` route, add:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  req.session.authenticated = true;
  // do what you would do next after authentication
} else {
  // do normal login procedures
}
```

Then, in your tests, in a `before` hook, you can use `superagent` to make a request to the `/login` route to authenticate:

```
describe('MyController', function() {
  var agent;

  before(function (done) {
    agent = require('superagent').agent('YOUR_APP_URL');

    // authenticate
    agent
      .post('/login')
      .end(done)
  });

  // in your tests, use the same agent to make future requests
  describe('#someAction', function() {
    it('should do something', function(done) {
      agent.
        .post('someAction')
        .end(function (err, res) {
          // should work!
        });
    });
  });
});
```

It's just an idea - you can adapt this approach to however you're checking sessions. This works for my Sails app using Mocha for tests.